# When will Hardy's inequality for integral become equality?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, lp-spaces

The Hardy's inequality for integrals asserts that

> Let $f:(0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be in $L^p$, $1<p<\infty$. Let $F(x) = \frac{1}{x} \int_0 ^x f(t)dt$. Then $F\in L^p$ and $\|F\|_p \leq \frac{p}{p-1} \|f\|_p$.

My question is

> When will the inequality becomes equality? How do we prove it?

As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality#Proof_of_the_inequality) says, the equality holds if and only if $f(x) = 0$ almost everywhere. However, there is no proof for this on Wikipedia. It seems that the only inequality used in the proof of Hardy's inequality is Minkowski's inequality. But I can't obtain the desired conclusion from when Minkowski's inequality becomes an equality.

Any comments are appreciated.